# How can I get combinationId from array of id_attributes

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I use the `Cart::updateQty()` function in my module for `prestashop`. I'd like also to use the `$id_product_attribute` parameter, but I'm unable to find the desired value for this when I have array of `id_attributes` only. 
I need behavior similar to the default selecting product attributes on the product page and then adding it to cart, but I'd like to do this on the server side.

What I was able to find out is that when I'm changing a product attributes on the product page, the `html` input with `id="idCombination"`
[#idCombination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH9cK.png)
 is being filled with a proper value and then it's being POST'ed with ajax to the server. Unfortunately, I cannot work out how the actual searching is being made and how to do this in js or php code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default product page these combinations are transferred with a variable `$combination` within a `ProductController.php` with a method `assignAttributesGroups()` and then defined a js variable inside `product.tpl` via condition

```
{if isset($combinations) && $combinations}
    {addJsDef combinations=$combinations}
{/if}
```

after that everithing going on in a `product.js` file which do all switch job and substitute `id="idCombination"` after each changing.
So you can to repeat a default approach to implement your requirements even though it looks a bit complicated. Also, I think you don't need such a completed $combination variable with all that information and you can add only that what you need. I hope it clarifies you a direction to work.

Comment: I've managed to achieve what I wanted using the js variable called 'combinations'.
`function getIdCombination(a, b, c, d) {
 var attributes = [a, b, c, d];
 var result = combinations.find((element)=>isEqual(element.idsAttributes, [a, b, c, d]));
 if (result) {
  return result.idCombination;
 }
 else {
  return 0;
 }
}`
I'm aware that it could be done more generic, but i need this for one specific product only. The 'isEqual' function is a helper function, which I've found on this [link](https://gomakethings.com/check-if-two-arrays-or-objects-are-equal-with-javascript/)